# Receiving an error when synching CiviCRMmember role and Drupal role

Tags: civimember

I'm running into an issue where I receive an error message when attempting to setup and manually sync CiviCRM Membership with Drupal Roles. I receive the following error message:

Error message
There was an error. CiviMember Memberships and Drupal Roles could not be synchronized.

When I attempt to import the syc rule in Drupal I receive the following error message:

Error message
Integrity check for the imported configuration failed. Error message: Unknown action civicrm_entity_action_create_user..

Any insight to what I may be missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which versions of CiviCRM, Drupal and civicrm_entity are you using?

Comment: maybe turn civicrm_entity off while you try this

Comment: Civi 4.6.28, Durpal 7.54 and civicrm_entity 2.0

Comment: I did turn off crm_entity and no success.